# Using hashtable instead of database system

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, hashmap, hashtable

I was asked to develop a login system using html,jsp and servlets. The login page should ask the user for user-id and password and after authentication should display a welcome message. There should also be provisions for adding a new user and changing the password of an existing user. However the catch here is that I have been asked to use a hashtable instead of a database system. I have a fairly good idea of implementing this system with Oracle . As far as I know in core java the scope of a hashtable/hashmap is the life of the program itself.When the program ends the hashtable values are lost. Is it different if I implement a hashmap in a servlet?If it is how should I proceed?

Comment: It isn't any different in a servlet. You should ask for clarification of how the data is to be persisted, and, incidentally, what security is required around it. For example, a text file or a serialized file would both contain passwords in clear text, which is violently insecure.

Comment: What are the business requirements. I already know the answer: there are none

Comment: Since when is it mandatory that a textfile contain clear text credentials @EJP

Comment: Its an homework assignment.The main thing is implementing it.

Comment: @AsConfused If it contained encrypted passwords it would still be insecure, and if it contained encrypted or hashed passwords it wouldn't be a text file, it would be binary. They would have to be hex- or base-36 or base-64 encoded at least. None of this is mentioned in the question. All this is exactly what the OP needs to ask about.

Comment: @ejp i didnt want the OP to leave thinking credentials hashed or encrypted can't be in a text file which they can and it is text. Text is different than `clear text`. The latter is generally understood in crypto to mean `as you would type it`. This comment is meant for those that follow as you already know this.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know in core java the scope of a hashtable/hashmap is the life of the program itself.

Not necessarily.  It depends on how your application handles the hashmap.  However, you are correct in the sense that the lifetime is *no longer* than the lifetime of the application.

> When the program ends the hashtable values are lost.

Correct.

> Is it different if I implement a hashmap in a servlet?

No.  When the appserver exits the hashmap will be gone.

---

So the question you haven't asked is how to deal with this "requirement".  I suggest the following:

- Find out if the state of the login system (i.e. the user names and passwords) is supposed to persist over restarts of your webserver.  If not, then using a `HashMap`.
- If it is required to persist then you need to find a way to save the state of a `HashMap` without using a database.  There are various possibilities:

  - Use Java Object Serialization to save the datastructure and load it again.
  - Use a "binding" technology to serialize as XML or JSON or similar.
  - Write an ad-hoc mechanism that saves the data structure to a file and reloads it.

The problem is that it is tricky to implement the save / reload in a way that is "bomb-proof"; i.e. that won't lose or corrupt state in the event of a bug, the application being killed, the power failing and so on.  A decent database deals with these things, which is why a database is the preferred implementation approach.

---

The other thing to note is that it is bad practice to store actual passwords, either in the clear or encrypted.  This applies, independently of how you implement persistence of the login system's state.  Instead, you should be hashing the user's password together with a "salt", and comparing that against a previously recorded hash.

---

> Its an homework assignment.The main thing is implementing it.

That means you can probably ignore the security and robustness concerns I've raised above.  (But in a real world system ... you shouldn't!)

Comment: Yeah , thanks for the answer, Sir. I am a beginner in java web development and started learning it about 2 weeks ago. So  i am not worrying about security that much. If I am able to build a simple application I am happy. Of course in time I would like to come back and make the system more robust.But for now I am happy with a very basic scheme of things.

Comment: I understand.  However, it was not clear from your Question that this was just a homework exercise.

Comment: Yes , that's because I felt I should at least know the problems incurred in it's real world implementation. And I have seen questions being not treated seriously because they are just homework assignments.

Comment: There's a good reason why homework questions are often not treated seriously.  It is that a lot of times the question is not really interested in the answer.  Often, all they want is something to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Steps which you can follow for a simple solution

1) while user registers to the application,create a properties/text file and store the key-value pairs with login id as key and password as value or you can consider xml or json formats. May be if you need to have some security consider using secure hashing algorithm.

2) when you stop the application, the credentials will be stored in your file instead of db.

3) when the application starts up for the next time you can create a map and load the key value pairs from the stored file or you can use directly using the properties file using java io to validate the credentials.